# How to select constant value if the Considered value not found?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, group-by

**First of all, i'm sorry for bad title that i'm selected for this question. :)**

In my database i have **Employee** and **Comment** tables as you seen below. Each employee can save his/her activities in **Comment** table and the manager can see the report of employees activity.

[image]

I'm using this query to select the employees activity for each month in the specific **Year**.

```
SELECT  Month ,
    ISNULL(( SELECT ( FirstName + '' + LastName )
             FROM   dbo.Employee
             WHERE  EmployeeID = C.EmployeeID
           ), '') [Name] ,
    ISNULL(COUNT(EmployeeID), 0) [Count]
FROM    dbo.Comment AS C
WHERE Year = 1393
GROUP BY Month ,
        EmployeeID
ORDER BY C.EmployeeID
```

and the result is:

[image]

but i want to do this, if each of employees haven't any activity in each month, then select row like `Month|Name|0` for that month and employee.

How can i do that?

**Update**
I'm changed the query to this:

```
DECLARE @aa TABLE ( m INT )

DECLARE @c INT= 1

WHILE @c < 13
    BEGIN
        INSERT  INTO @aa
                ( m )
        VALUES  ( @c  -- m - int
                  )
        SET @c = @c + 1

    END

SELECT  m ,
        ( SELECT    ( FirstName + ' ' + LastName )
          FROM      dbo.Employee
          WHERE     EmployeeID = C.EmployeeID
        ) [Name] ,
        COUNT(CommentID) [Count]
FROM    dbo.Comment AS C
        RIGHT JOIN @aa ON m = Month
GROUP BY m ,
        EmployeeID
ORDER BY m
```

and then the result is:

[image]

but i want to have this Result:

[image]

Comment: RIGHT JOIN with a calendar table,essentially 12 ints.

Comment: How can i do that in **EntityFramework**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one method, using a CTE and a CROSS JOIN to get all employee/month combinations.

```
WITH
    employees AS (
        SELECT 
            EmployeeID
            , FirstName + '' + LastName AS Name
        FROM   dbo.Employee
    )
    ,months AS (
        SELECT month FROM (VALUES(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(8),(10),(11),(12)) AS months(Month)
    )
SELECT
     m.Month
    ,e.Name
    ,(SELECT COUNT(*) 
        FROM dbo.Comment AS c 
        WHERE 
            c.EmployeeID = e.EmployeeID 
            AND c.Month = m.Month
            AND c.Year = 1393
    ) AS Count
FROM months AS m
CROSS JOIN employees AS e
ORDER BY
     Month
    ,Name;
```

Comment: How can i do that with **linq** queries? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a table called Months and insert data from 1 to 12 in it. Then in entityframework you can create the following query to get the data from comments,employees and months table:

```
var q = from m  in stackExchangeExampleEntities.Months
                from e in stackExchangeExampleEntities.Employees
            select new
            {
                EmployeeName = e.FirstName,
                Month = m.Id,
                Count = (from c in stackExchangeExampleEntities.Comments
                        where c.EmployeeId ==e.EmployeeId && c.Month == m.Id && c.Year == 1393
                        select c).Count()


            };
        foreach (var data in q)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(data.Month + "," + data.EmployeeName +"," + data.Count);
        }
```